# fatal error: bms_class_helper_data not found

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error, helper, aws

I created a custom module and its gives a error "fatal error: bms_class_helper_data not found " after that i removed the complete module, layout file and data enabler file and database, but still it is displaying a same error, why the error still displaying, even i cleared the cache also. and in AWS server instance screen shot it is showing **out of memory : kill process or sacrifice child** what may be the problem

[image]

And Cache files are not storing in /var/cache folder, in testing same error occur, i removed cache manually from /var/cache and its woking fine, but in live cache files are not storing in /var/cache folder

Comment: Can you provide helper/data.php file code and where it is used as helper file?

Comment: But i removed the entire module, layout file, database, module enabler all the files i removed, but still the error is displaying